# Simple SET not working in batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, atlassian-sourcetree

*Disclaimer: I'm not a batch files guru, just digging my way with the help of Google and SO. Also note that I'm trying to run this batch file as a Custom Action in SourceTree.*

The following simple SET command doesn't seem to assign value to the variable:

```
SET MYVAR = %1
ECHO "%MYVAR%"
ECHO "!MYVAR!"
ECHO %1
```

The first ECHO above returns `""`; the second one `"!MYVAR!"`, whereas the last one returns the actual value of command-line parameter. How can I assign value to `MVAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is sensitive to spaces on each side of the `=`. You are setting a variable named `myvar[Space}`

Comment: Can't believe this is correct. This is the first language in my knowledge that works like that (though I know only a handful of them). Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @dotNET: most UNIX shells (including Bash) are the same.  It is consistent with the environment block which resides in every process `VAR=VALUE`.  That format comes from C `setenv` and `getenv` etc.

Comment: It's a script, not a computer language, and that's one of the major differences. There's no precompiler to strip unnecessary whitespace. Have you ever seen how picky Python is about whitespace? It's because it's also not a compiled language. Batch files are actually run one line at a time; you can add a 'pause' and while it's paused, add a new command under that line (and save the script file) and when you resume from the 'pause', it will run that newly-added command. Any `set /p` input prompt allows you to take over the program. Bash won't though because it's not a joke like .bat files.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple: Not sure if I agree with that compiled/interpreted argument. Both PHP and GW-BASIC are interpreted, yet allow unnecessary white spaces. You may be correct about Python though, I haven't used it.

Comment: @dotNET Reading it again two years later I also have my qualms with my earlier note. Python is a fairly unique case in that whitespace *as indentation* is a fundamental part of its syntax; its handling of whitespace is unrelated to its interpreted nature. Batch has these specific sensitivities to whitespace because its interpreter is unsophisticated. If I could edit the note, I would remove the first four sentences (the ones that don't deal in testable specifics). I stand by the rest.