# Echo is off, even if variable has the value

Tags: shell, batch-file, echo

I have this code, and I am getting "Echo is off". I know this means variable does not have a value whenever we get "Echo is off". but in following case value is there.

```
@echo off
set message = Hello World 
echo %message%
```

Comment: The space is part of the variable name in the SET command. Remove the spaces.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple SET not working in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277001/simple-set-not-working-in-batch-file)

Comment: I was searching more along the lines of "Echo is off". which I cant find. That is why I posted the question, it may help anyone facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Squashman, anyone who will face same issue. get rid of the space between 'message' and '='

```
@echo off
set message= Hello World 
echo %message%
```

Comment: I would have done "set message=Hello World" else your gonna get it 1 space off.